# I recieved Serial data from sensor what i want only last 20 bytes of data and want to save it in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, pyserial

I am getting data from a Sensor on the UART1 port of beaglebone. but I want only the last 20 bytes of data.
But facing these problems with python code.
First: -

```
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyO1"

ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
#ser.timeout = None          #block read
ser.timeout = 5 

   ser.open()
   file.open("data.txt","w")

time.sleep(5)  #give the serial port sometime to receive the data
while True:
     data = ord(ser.read())
     print(data)
     file.write(data)
```

with this code, I can print the data. What I don't know how to end the loop when all the data is received and only the last 10 or 20 Bytes will store in a file.
I used ord(ser.read) otherwise data will be like this.

```
�

u
�

u
�
```

ASCII. To get data in Decimal I used ord(data) get data like this

```
79
1
1
12
0
13
116
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please fix the indentation of your :)

Comment: "What I don't know how to end the loop when all the data is received" Just to make sure, do you only want to know how to break the loop or do you also want to know how to detect that all the data was received?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect and then break the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the data in your file, create a list, remove the last (list's first element) data point, and append (to the end of the list) the new one, and save it.

```
while True:
    text = file.readlines()
    text = [line.strip() for line in text]
    try:
        data = ord(ser.read())
    except:
        break
    if len(text) == 20:
        text.pop(0)
    text.append(data)
    file.write('\n'.join(text))
```

Full Code:

```
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyO1"

ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
#ser.timeout = None          #block read
ser.timeout = 5 

ser.open()
file.open("data.txt","w")

time.sleep(5)  #give the serial port sometime to receive the data
while True:
    text = file.readlines()
    text = [line.strip() for line in text]
    try:
        data = ord(ser.read())
    except:
        break
    if len(text) == 20:
        text.pop(0)
    text.append(data)
    file.write('\n'.join(text))

file.close()
```

You were not clear about breaking out of the loop, so I left that part out. If you would like to break after the 20th data point, you should check the list's length, and if equals to 20, break.

Comment: Got this error: -   File "new1.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = ord(ser.read()).split('\n')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: sorry to bother you again but this is the same error I'm getting again. see what happens. When I Rx all the data from sensor. instead of exiting the loop, it tries to read more data then this error------------------------------->92
78
1
1
12
0
13
119
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new1.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = ord(ser.read())
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found

Comment: 92 78 1 1 12 13 119 is the data. 119 is the last byte of data.